placement of "usually"
I have made up the sentences below.
(1) Jack said people usually make requests politely using the word, please.
(2) Jack said usually people make requests politely using the word, please.
My non-native friends think it's grammatically wrong to put "usually" before a subject, so (2) is wrong. What is your opinion? Thank you.

It's not wrong to do that, but if you put usually before the verb it would be better to separate it out with commas.

Jack said [that], usually, people make requests politely by using the word please.

(If you are referring to the use of a particular word, it's best to emphasise it by using italics or inverted commas.)
